# magento when go on one page checkout page gose blank no error

Tags: magento, opc

magento when go on one page checkout page gose blank on my theme and also on default theme no error on Magento ver. 1.9.2.4 no idea what happening so if you have any solution for related it let me send your answer ASAP
Thanks
Martin

Comment: Are you facing this for a fresh install with no changes? or have you installed modules?. Also please check in console if you are getting any error. Or you may enable logging and check for logs.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. This will help getting useful answers. Without punctuation, your question is very balky to read

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?